# Unable to select from the drop-down option

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Unable to select "Delhi" from the drop down option.....the x-path might be wrong...

```
public class spicejet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\Colin\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.spicejet.com/");

        driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_mainContent_rbtnl_Trip_0")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_mainContent_ddl_originStation1_CTXT")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@text,'Kochi')]")).click();

        driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_mainContent_ddl_destinationStation1_CTXT")).click();
       List<WebElement> list=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'dropdownDiv')]//ul//li//a"));
        System.out.println(list.size());
        for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(list.get(i).getText());
            if(list.get(i).getText().contains("Delhi (DEL)"));{
        list.get(i).click();
        break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath is correct. However there is terminator `;` used with your `if` condition like `if(list.get(i).getText().contains("Delhi (DEL)"));` because of which the `if` condition is getting terminated and the first element from the list is getting selected from the line of code mentioned in the next line. You need to remove `;` from the `if` condition and then it would work just fine.

Addition to that, you can also improve your xpath with the one i am mentioning below:

```
List<WebElement> list=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='dropdownDiv']//li"));
```